# How to find files with special characters in VB (like MySQL does)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, unicode

If I search for e.g. "dëër" in MySql, it will return all results like dëer, deer, Déér and so on.

I need to perform a file.delete(deer) , where all possibilities will be deleted.

Can this be done in VB?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. If you use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles, it accepts a string argument that represents the search pattern, but per the documentation `This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions.` So while you could apply a search pattern like `d**r` this would also pickup files like "door".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about the file's extension, you could do something like this:

Define some static fields to optimize normalization:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly Encoder As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8")
Private Shared ReadOnly Decoder As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
```

Define a function that simplifies the string (removes accents):

```
Private Shared Function Simplify(text As String) As String
    If (text Is Nothing) Then Return Nothing
    text = text.Normalize()
    Dim binary As Byte() = Encoder.GetBytes(text)
    Return Decoder.GetString(binary)
End Function
```

Define two overloaded functions that match file names:

```
Private Shared Function GetMatchingFilePath(folderPath As String, ParamArray includeFilter As String()) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim myIncludeFilter As IEnumerable(Of String) = includeFilter
    Return GetMatchingFilePath(folderPath, myIncludeFilter)
End Function

Private Shared Iterator Function GetMatchingFilePath(folderPath As String, includeFilters As IEnumerable(Of String)) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    If (includeFilters Is Nothing) Then Return
    includeFilters = includeFilters.Where(Function(e) e IsNot Nothing).Select(Function(e) Simplify(e)).Distinct()
    For Each filePath As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
        Dim fileName As String = Simplify(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath))
        For Each includeFilter In includeFilters
            If StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(fileName, includeFilter) Then
                Yield filePath
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

And use it like this:

```
For Each filePath As String In GetMatchingFilePath("C:\Temp", "dëër")
    File.Delete(filePath)
Next
```

Comment: Be aware that although some letters appear to be variations through use of accents and the like, and can be equated, some are distinct. For example, in Spanish, you could equate "e" with "é" but not "n" with "ñ", the latter being a separate character in the Spanish alphabet. I'm not sure what impact that might have on the requirement, or the solution.